# Why is Blender so Slow for only one File?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am kind of new to Blender but recently I was working on a monster, just learning how to model, when Blender started lagging unbearably bad, out of the blue. I don't think I changed anything in settings. The file has 43k verts, which doesn't seem like it should be a lot. I have tried restarting Blender multiple tries. I have tried opening the default File and blender works just fine on that file.

[image: Image of the UI]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure how to send the blend file for you to see.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ujudkehgglcyx7r/Monster.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have enabled [dupliframes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliframes.html), which is set to make 100 duplicates of your model giving your file a total of nearly 4.3 million vertices.

You can find this setting in the object properties under Duplication.

[image: dupliframes]